# Dúvida com a nomenclatura CSS

Tags: css

O `CSS` pode ser aplicado de três maneiras diferentes em um documento `HTML`:

- dentro da própria tag (`inline`):

```
  <body>
    <h1 style='color: red';> Hello World </h1>
  </body>
```

- dentro da tag `head`:

```
<head>
  <style>
    .myclass {
     color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

- com um documento `.css` externo, dentro da tag `head`:

```
<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css_folder/css.css'>
</head>
```

Estas aplicações podem ser vistas na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dúvida:

- Como estas aplicações se inter-relacionam e;
- Qual é a relação entre elas e o nome "**C**ascading **S**tyle **S**heets"?

Comment: Ok. Creio que a decisão de marcar a pergunta como duplicata é válida. Só queria entender o que seria cada uma das letras do acrônimo **CSS**. Por exemplo, por que **cascata**, por que **style** e por que **sheet**. Parece uma dúvida infantil, mas como estou a começar a usar o CSS agora, estes termo  estão confusos para mim. Ora, na Internet há vários modelos e explicações divergentes. Grato.

Comment: Neves é exatamente do jeito que se traduz. "Folha de estilo em cascata", ou seja é top down, de cima para baixo, sendo que o que vem abaixo tem prioridade. Se vc declara no topo `body {bg:red}` e lá no final da "cascata" `body {bg:blue}` o background fica azul e não red, pois a cascata não retrocede. A imagem da sua pergunta, mais tem a ver com a hierarquia e prioridade de seletor no hora de aplica o CSS e não é tão relacionada com o termo "cascata style sheet" mais propriamente ...

Comment: *A imagem da sua pergunta, mais tem a ver com a hierarquia e prioridade de seletor no hora de aplica o CSS e não é tão relacionada com o termo "cascata style sheet" mais propriamente*. Como eu disse, comecei o estudo em CSS há alguns dias. Por isso a confusão de conceitos.  Alguns estão desconexos para mim. Mas obrigado por esclarecer a dúvida e desculpe se formulei a pergunta de forma imprecisa.

Comment: Tranquilo Neves, leia as perguntas marcadas que já vai ser um bom começo para entender bem os fundamentos do CSS. Sucesso []´s